# If we say L ⊂ {a, b, c}* then is L an infinite language?

Tags: formal-languages

I wonder if we say L ⊂ {a, b, c}* then is L an infinite language?
I think Kleene star makes me think L is an infinite language.

Answer (score 3):

$L$ is not *necessarily* an infinite language. $\{a,b,c\}^*$ is an infinite language, but you've written $L\subset\{a,b,c\}^*$, and infinite sets can (and do) have finite subsets. Consider $L=\{a\}$, then $L\subset\{a,b,c\}^*$ but $\lvert L\rvert=1<\infty$

Comment: Can L also be an infinite language if L ⊂ {a, b, c}*?

Comment: Yes, it can be either finite or infinite. For an example of an infinite proper subset of $\{a,b,c\}^*$ consider $L=\{a\}^*$